# Get derived class type from a base's class static method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, inheritance

i would like to get the type of the derived class from a static method of its base class.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

```
class BaseClass {
  static void Ping () {
     Type t = this.GetType(); // should be DerivedClass, but it is not possible with a static method
  }
}
class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}

// somewhere in the code
DerivedClass.Ping();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the code emitted for `BaseClass.Ping()` and `DerivedClass.Ping()` is the same, so making the method static without giving it any arguments won't work. Try passing the type as an argument or through a generic type parameter (on which you can enforce an inheritance constraint).

```
class BaseClass {
    static void Ping<T>() where T : BaseClass {
        Type t = typeof(T);
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
BaseClass.Ping<DerivedClass>();
```

Answer (score 40):

This can be accomplished easily using the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
class BaseClass<T>
    where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    static void SomeMethod() {
        var t = typeof(T);  // gets type of derived class
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass> {}
```

call the method:

```
DerivedClass.SomeMethod();
```

This solution adds a small amount of boilerplate overhead because you have to template the base class with the derived class.

It's also restrictive if your inheritance tree has more than two levels.  In this case, you will have to choose whether to pass through the template argument or impose the current type on its children with respect to calls to your static method.

And by templates I, of course, mean generics.

Comment: Great Technique! Thanks! This pattern helped me to avoid Reflection

Comment: For brevity, I was able to get this to work without the type constraint, i.e. `class BaseClass<T>`.

Comment: @InteXX The type constraint is not required, but it's there for your benefit to prevent runtime errors

Comment: *"prevent runtime errors"* Hm, interesting. Such as... ?

Comment: OP's request is to identify which child type of this class is calling the static method. If you let the child class pass any type as T, then your static method will get whatever type the programmer specifies, which can be anything. You're broken the contract with the static method, and many operations can lead to runtime errors, such as casts, and any branching based on type matching.

Comment: One caveat with this approach (which turned out to be a benefit in one of our designs) is the static is ultimately defined on the fully-resolved base type, including the generic type parameter.  There for if you defined `static int n = 0` in the base class, then typed it for both `BaseClass<Foo>` and `BaseClass<Laa>`, each subclass 'type' would have its own copy of the static.  To get around this, we use the chain `BaseClass -> TypedBaseClass<T> -> Subclass: TypedBaseClass<Subclass>` where we only know `T` in the generic version, but all share statics from the non-generic base version.

Answer (score 4):

A static method is defined on the type.  There is no "this".  You'll need to make this an instance method, instead:

```
class BaseClass {
    public void Ping() {
        Type t = this.GetType(); // This will work, since "this" has meaning here...
    }
```

You can then do:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}

DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();
instance.Ping();
```

Comment: I need to accomplish this, if it is possible, with a static method.

Comment: @Marco: You'll need to pass in an instance or a type, then.  There is no way to get a derived type otherwise.

Comment: this.GetType() returns BaseClass, and not DerivedClass.

Comment: @Luca: this.GetType() will return the type of this at runtime - which will be the derived class if you're actually in the derived class.

Answer (score 3):

In short this is what I tried to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458225/how-do-i-get-the-subclass-type-object-in-a-static-superclass-function-in-net-us/3170222#3170222). It uses one interface to unify all derived classes and let them all call the same static method from the base class without passing a Type.

```
public interface IDerived
{
}
public class BaseClass<T> where T : IDerived
{
    public static void Ping()
    {
        //here you have T = the derived type
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>, IDerived
{
    //with : BaseClass<DerivedClass> we are defining the T above
}
public class ExampleApp
{
    public void Main()
    {
        //here we can call the BaseClass's static method through DerivedClass
        //and it will know what Type calls it
        DerivedClass.Ping();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the derived class from a static method. As an example to illustrate why, imagine BaseClass has 2 subclasses - DerivedClass and AnotherDerivedClass - which one should be returned? Unlike polymorphic non-static methods, there is no possible association with a derived class calling a static method on a base class - the compile time type and runtime type are the same with a static method call.

You can either make the method non-static, so you then get the correct type via polymorphism, or create static method "overrides" in the subclasses, e.g.

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   void Ping() { 
     BaseClass.Ping();
     // or alternatively
     BaseClass.Ping(Type.GetType("DerivedClass"));
   }
}
```

Your client code can then call the method in the derived class to explicitly indicate it want's the derived class version. If necessary, you might then also pass the DerivedClass type as a parameter to the base class method, to provide context that the method was called via the derived class.

Comment: take a look at my answer above to know the type of a derived class inside a baseclass' static method

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (not tested)

```
Type t = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
```

Comment: Just tested, it returns the base class type.

Comment: When you're defining a static method, the method is on the type itself (BaseClass) - there is no instance, hence no way for it to know it's a "derived class"...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the methods that are there already?

If you have

```
class BaseClass {}
partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}
```

You can look at

```
DerivedClass.GetType().BaseType;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work for this case (and several similar ones elsewhere on SO). Perf won't be too good, but if this is infrequent, that won't be a problem.

Create a stacktrace and parse it looking for a derived class. In the general case this wouldn't be too reliable or might not even work, but **in specific cases**, like that in the OP, I believe this will work fine. In Powershell:

```
$strace = (new-object diagnostics.stacktrace).tostring()
#
$frames = $strace -split "   at "
$typesFromFrames = $frames | select -skip 1| # skip blank line at the beginning
   % { ($_ -split "\(",2)[0]} |                 # Get rid of parameters string
   % {$_.substring(0,$_.lastindexof("."))} |    # Get rid of method name
   $ {$_ -as [type]}
#
# In powershell a lot of the frames on the stack have private classes
#  So $typesFromFrames.count is quite a bit smaller than $frames.count
#  For the OP, I don't think this will be a problem because:
#   1. PS isn't being used
#   2. The derived class in the OP isn't private 
#        (if it is then tweaks will be needed)
#
$derivedOnStack = $typesFromFrames | ? { $_.issubclassof( [BaseClass])}
```

Hopefully there will just be one element in $derivedOnStack, but it will depend on the particulars of the application. Some experimentation will be required.