# How to get the class Type in a base class static method in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inheritance

All I want to do is similar to:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public static Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(BaseClass);
    }
}
```

But when I derive it

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

I want to get

```
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(DerivedClass), DerivedClass.GetType());
```

How to change the BaseClass to make this assertion true?

Comment: That won't even compile - can you clarify your intent?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why would you want to call `GetType` from a static method?

Comment: @asawyer @Marc I correct the sample, now it compiles and I tested it

Comment: @Gabe It's an oversimplified example, that's why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Marc @Gabe Actually `GetType` in my code (not in the example) is `CreateServiceHost` which needs to know which of the derived service classes is calling it.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need a static method? What's your end goal?

Comment: @Gabe is to create `ServiceHost` which uses the type of the current class as an argument to its constructor

Comment: @Jeff I don't need to instantiate the service class to instantiate a ServiceHost. But I gave up of this question already since you answered it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064227/get-derived-class-type-from-a-bases-class-static-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are not inherited.

The compiler substitutes `BaseClass` for `DerivedClass` when calling a base class' static methods through one of its derived classes. For example, here's the IL code for a call to `DerivedClass.GetType()`:

```
IL_0002:  call   class [mscorlib]System.Type Tests.Program/BaseClass::GetType()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because your only route to a derived type from one of its bases is from an instance - and static methods don't take an instance.

I'm hoping that your example is for simplicity because otherwise re-implementing GetType() seems a bit pointless - since the `object.GetType()` will do exactly what you want.

If you actually need to do this via a statically invoked method - you can't because no type information is actually available to a static method (as I say in the first paragraph).

If you actually invoking this method via an instance (but I must ask why!?) then you can do one of the following

a) Make your method an instance method on the base.  It can then do `this.GetType()` (using the .Net base method) and it'll return the ultimate subtype of the instance.

b) Define an extension method for `BaseClass` that does something very similar:

```
public static Type GetType2(this BaseClass instance)
{
  return instance.GetType();
}
```