# Is it possible to get a subclass type when calling a static method on a base class (similar to Swift's 'self')?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-methods, c#-9.0

Converting some code from Swift to C#.  There's a need in a base class's static method implementation to know which concrete type that method was called against.

In Swift, when in an instance method, you use `self` (lowercase) to get that instance.  This is equivalent to using `this` in C#.  To get the instance *type*, you use `Self` (uppercase) which is the equivalent of C#'s `this.GetType()`.

However, Swift also lets you use lower-cased `self` from within a static method to get the type the static was called against (as opposed to the type where it was defined.)  I'm trying to find if C# has something similar.  We're using C# 9 if it matters.

Here's a simple example showing what we're after. Note, this will not compile. It's example only since `self` isn't known to C#.

```cs
public class BaseClass {

    public static void DoSomethingStatic(){

        // Looking for the equivalent of Swift's 'self' in a static method
        // which returns the concrete type, including when called from a derived class
        Debug.WriteLine($"Static method called on the type {self.FullName}.");
    }

    public void DoSomethingInstance(){

        // Swift's 'Self' in an instance method is equivalent to C#'s `this.GetType()`
        Debug.WriteLine($"Instance method called on the type {this.GetType().FullName}.");
    }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass {}
```

Now this is easily possible with instance methods thanks to using `this.GetType()`:

```cs
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.DoSomethingInstance();
```

Output:

```
Instance method called on the type MyClass.
```

But we're hoping to achieve the same thing from a static exposed via the base class, like this...

```cs
MyClass.DoSomethingStatic();
```

Output:

```
Static method called on the type MyClass.
```

So is this possible in C#9?

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

Comment: What you're talking about isn't possible. `MyClass.DoSomethingStatic` doesn't actually exist, even though you can call it that way. You're still calling `BaseClass.DoSomethingStatic`.

Comment: Such a shame. It really allows flexibility in API design along with lots of cool covariant-like types of behaviors.  One of the many reasons I love Swift so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get derived class type from a base's class static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064227/get-derived-class-type-from-a-bases-class-static-method)

Comment: The generic hack is quite interesting. Though I think it definitely is hackery, I couldn't imaging why i would ever need it. Maybe someone has a use case though.

Comment: Yeah, that's the work-around we're using.  Was hoping not to have to make passing it down explicit because technically there's nothing stopping you from passing down *any* class that matches the constraint.  (e.g. Base class A with subclasses B and C.  You can call the method on C but passing the type parameter B (or A!) and it won't complain.) BUT... in light of any other solution, that will work.

Comment: This may sorta come in a future version of C#. See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1711 which will allow you to define abstract static methods.

Comment: Not quite what I'm after as I don't want a subclass to override it or anything. I just want to know which actual type it was called on from within the method in the base class.